# To enable Radio button of one radio group and disable the other radio group when selected

Tags: javascript, python

I want to enable topping only after Pizza is selected I want to either disable topping or from appearing before pizza is selected.

```
<legend>Choose the pizza wrap type ?</legend>
<div class="control-group">//radio group
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="pizza" id="pizza3"value="3" {% if pizza.rel == 3%}
 checked {% endif %}>
 Vegan
</label><br>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="pizza" id="pizza2" value="2" {% if pizza.rel == 2 %} 
 checked {% endif %}>
 Vegetarian
</label><br>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="pizza" id="pizza1" value="1" {% if 
pizza.rel == 1 %} checked {% endif %}>
Non vegetarian
</label><br>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="pizza" id="pizza0" value="0" {% if 
 pizza.rel == 0 %} checked {% endif %}>
 Halal meat
</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="pizza" onclick="captureSelection()">   
</button>
</div>

<h5>Toppings?</h5>
<div class="control-group">     
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="topping" id="topping3" value="3" {% if topping.top == 3
%} checked {% endif %}>
Vegan 
</label><br>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="topping" id="topping2" value="2" {% if topping.top == 2 
%} checked {% endif %}>
Veggie
</label><br>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="topping" id="topping1" value="1" {% if topping.top == 1
%} checked {% endif %}>
Meat
</label><br>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="topping" id="topping0" value="0" {% if topping.top == 0 
%} checked {% endif %}>
Halal meat
</label>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="topping" onclick="captureSelection()">  
</button>
</div>
```

function I am using to check if the radio button is checked or not should I do the for loop to check with if one of the radio buttons is checked from pizza ??

```
function captureSelection(){ 
    var u = document.getElementById('relevance');
    var t = document.getElementById ('topic');
    if (u.value=='unchecked' && u.value ==''){
        t.disable='true';
    }
    else (u.value=='checked'){
        t.enable='true';
    }
}
```

Comment: You want toppings to get enabled when you click on the button after selecting pizza? or you want that when you click on pizza radio, toppings should be enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you may try: [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fQTUp/273/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".a").click(function () {
        $(".b").prop('checked', false);
    });
    $(".b").click(function () {
        $(".a").prop('checked', false);
    });
});
</script>
```

Note: I have Added classes to your input type radio.

Comment: He is not using jQuery

Comment: @palsingh: I can see that, but don't you think it wud be better to use Jquery rather than javascript.